# How to detect a double-click outside of vb.net form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, events, double-click

**Setup Environment:**

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and writing code in vb.net (with .NET Framework 4).

**My goal:**

1. Use `Shell("C:\myprogram.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)` to open a new application
2. With new application open as the active window, recognize when user double clicks

If the active window is a vb.net form, it's simple to recognize double click event like so:

> `Private Sub Button2_DoubleClick(......) Handles Button2.DoubleClick`
>
> `End Sub`

**This code works to recognize a SINGLE left click:**

- This is *Form1.vb*

  ```
  Public Class Form1

      Private WithEvents MouseDetector As MouseDetector

      Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

          MouseDetector = New MouseDetector

      End Sub

      Private Sub MouseDetector_MouseLeftButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MouseDetector.MouseLeftButtonClick

          'Left click occurred
          MsgBox("Left click")

      End Sub

  End Class
  ```

- Here's the Enum in *MouseDetector.vb*

  ```
  Private Enum MouseMessages
      WM_LeftButtonDown = 513
      WM_LeftButtonUp = 514
      WM_LeftDblClick = 515
      WM_RightButtonDown = 516
      WM_RightButtonUp = 517
      WM_RightDblClick = 518
  End Enum
  ```
- And here's the Function in *MouseDetector.vb* that recognizes the single click

  ```
  Private Function MouseHookProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
          If nCode < 0 Then
              Return CallNextHookEx(MouseHookID, nCode, wParam, lParam)
          End If
          Dim MouseData As MouseHookStruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, GetType(MouseHookStruct))
          Select Case wParam

              Case MouseMessages.WM_LeftButtonUp
                  RaiseEvent MouseLeftButtonClick(Nothing, New MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, MouseData.pt.x, MouseData.pt.y, 0))

          End Select
          Return CallNextHookEx(MouseHookID, nCode, wParam, lParam)
      End Function
  ```

[image: ScreenShot]

**How is it possible to recognize a DOUBLE click?**

Obviously there isn't a `MouseButtons.LeftDoubleclick`, but that's what I'm after.

Would someone be willing to give a suggestion on how to go about doing this?  I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: If you look at the http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/ project, they are handling the MouseDouble click events globally for both the Left and Right mouse buttons.

Comment: @MarkHall Thank you!  This worked perfectly.  Go ahead and post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the CodePlex [GlobalMouseKeyHook](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/) project, they are handling the MouseDouble click events globally for both the Left and Right mouse buttons.

> This library attaches to windows global hooks, tracks keyboard and mouse clicks and movement and raises common .NET events with KeyEventArgs and MouseEventArgs, so you can easily retrieve any information you need:
>   Mouse coordinates
>   Mouse buttons clicked
>   Mouse wheel scrolls
>   Key presses and releases
>   Special key states